# Limit c# model class parameter call to MS SQL server for non-existing table field

Tags: sql-server, c#

Working with database-first approach creating ASPNETCORE MVC web app with user authentication, I would like to override the way the parameters from IdentityUser class are queried to the database. The reason is the current implementation of IdentityUser has two new parameters NormalizedEmail and NormalizedUserName (which in my opinion retracts from Normalization).

Is there a way I can write the code below in the Model class so that those two parameters are not included in the query to the database or is that something that needs to be done in the controller class?

```
public class IdentityUser : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityUser
{
    public override string NormalizedUserName
    { get { return null; } set { value = null; } }
    public override string NormalizedEmail
    { get { return null; } set { value = null; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not far as I can tell, both parameters are part of the data model and as explained in this Issue [#351](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/351)

About Identity 3.0:

> ...Instead we compute a normalized representation of the user name and we
>   store it in a separate column so that lookups by normalized user name
>   should now be [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

So in other words, if you *"override the way the parameters from IdentityUser class are queried to the database"* in essence you'll be doing exactly the opposite the class intends to do.

Comment: That is the point of an override parameter/method, to change something about the base class. Also programming in part is about being able to transform things, ex dll classes and methods imported or referenced.